# MongoDB shards and config servers on the same server?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to deploy a simple MongoDB project. I've read the docs but couldn't find what I was looking for.
Is it a good idea to keep each of my config server instances on the same server as it's shard cluster?
Can you please tell the deployment requirements for a MongoDB with 3 shards and three Config servers and a Routing Instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q) Is it a good idea to keep each of my config server instances on the same server as it's shard cluster?

Ans= In practice config server should never be on same server as shard server, because config points to shard location where data resides, during failover when voting occurs and replica server comes as primary then there is no need to update in config if both are at different servers.